# WP medial file url doesn't come with https

Tags: wordpress, file, url, ssl, media

Recently I have added ssl in my wordpress site, i have done search replace http by https but still media file url showing with http://

What can be a posible issue here? How to resolve it?

Here is an screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i were able to fix it. There is an hard coded http in file related with media.